# Pivoting of dataframe by year and month

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame like this:

```
Factory Serial_number year  month   LT  Order  Minimum  Lot   Stock  Value 
    xxx       123     2020   8      20   123     456    10     2000    3000
    xxx       123     2020   9      ..   ...    ...     ..      ...    4000
```

Desired output is:

```
Factory Serial_number year  month  LT   Order   Minimum  Lot    Stock   8.2020  9.2020
  xxx       123       2020   8     20     123     456     10     2000    3000    4000
```

I tried different method like stacking, pivoting but that did not give the exact result

```
 pd.pivot_table(df, values='Value', index=['Factory', 'Serial_number','Order','Minimum Lot','Stock'],
                    columns=['year','month']).reset_index()

    Ouput I get: 


                                               

                                                        year           2020    
                   
                                                        month            8        9       10        11  12  1   2   3   4   5   6   7
                Factory 12NC    Order   Minimum Lot   Stock                                             
                xxx   1233     8430.0   305.0          10675.200  35295.86   38735.9    29546.91    23004.1 25433.2 0.0 13547.6 27095.2 0.0 2686             0.0    0.0 0.0
                      1234       660.0  330.0          108.000   0.00   0.0 0.00    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
```

Comment: Do you try pivot by `set_index` and `unstack` ? Of by `pivot_table` ?

Comment: I tried by pivot table... I did not try by setting index and then unstack. @jezrael

Comment: can you add your pivot_table code to question? It should working well

Comment: can you add output from sample data of your code? All columns used for index parameter are duplicated like `Factory`, `Serial_number` ?

Comment: try remove `.reset_index()` first, then `df.columns = f'{a}.{b}' for b, a in df.columns]` and last `df = df.reset_index()`

Comment: Could you please elaborate more? I could not get exactly the desired output @jezrael

Comment: whats wrong here? Without data after your code not easy.

Comment: so `df = pd.pivot_table(df, values='Value', index=['Factory', 'Serial_number','Order','Minimum Lot','Stock'],
                    columns=['year','month'])`, then `df.columns = f'{a}.{b}' for b, a in df.columns]` and last `df = df.reset_index()` not working?

Comment: So first I run this df = pd.pivot_table(df, values='Value', index=['Factory', 'Serial_number','Order','Minimum Lot','Stock'],columns=['year','month']) 


                         Then in a separate line     df.columns = f'{a}.{b}' for b, a in df.columns] here it tells invalid syntax

Comment: opps, sorry, misisng one `[` need instead `df.columns = f'{a}.{b}' for b, a in df.columns]` using `df.columns = [f'{a}.{b}' for b, a in df.columns]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220040/discussion-between-rocky-and-jezrael).